# Get the parent directory for a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to get just the name of the parent directory for a file.

Example: When I have `path=/a/b/c/d/file`, I want only `d` and not `/a/b/c/d` (which I get from `dirname $path`) as output.

Is there any sophisticated way to do this?

Answer (score 48):

It sounds like you want the basename *of* the dirname:

```
$ filepath=/a/b/c/d/file
$ parentname="$(basename "$(dirname "$filepath")")"
$ echo "$parentname"
d
```

Comment: why am I receiving . instead of the parent directory on debian?

Comment: @Amir: Are you starting with a full path, or just a filename? If it's just a filename, the `dirname` command will assume it's in the current directory (aka ".").

Comment: well, I am using this: `parentname="$(basename "$(dirname "$pwd")")"`

Comment: @Amir: Shell variables are case sensitive, and `PWD` must be capitalized. Try `parentname="$(basename "$(dirname "$PWD")")"`.

Answer (score 8):

You can use pwd to get the current working directory, and use [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) to avoid forking it into another (sub)shell.

```
echo ${PWD##*/}
```

Edit: [proven source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1371283/1224832)

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the current directory. You could use `${path##*/}`

Comment: Please ignore this answer and use the "proven source" link. This answer has omitted the vital double quotes and thereby introduced a data-corrupting bug.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is a less-resource solution:

```
 $ filepath=/a/b/c/d/file
 $ echo ${${filepath%/*}##*/}
 d
```

**edit:** Sorry, nested expansion isn't possible in bash, but it works in zsh. Bash-version:

```
 $ filepath=/a/b/c/d/file
 $ path=${filepath%/*}
 $ echo ${path##*/}
 d
```

Comment: There are some edge cases this doesn't handle well, mainly when there isn't a full multilevel path. For example, try it with `filepath=file` or filepath=/file`.

Comment: Indeed. But what is the parent directory of `foofile`? If it isn't full path can't know (maybe if `foofile` is an existing file not only a "string").

Answer (score 2):

In bash, in one line:

```
$ dirname /a/b/c/d/file | sed 's,^\(.*/\)\?\([^/]*\),\2,'
```

Comment: can you please elaborate the procedures involved? it can be of help to future readers. also, please try not to write 1/2 line answers.

Comment: `dirname` gets the directory in which `file` supposedly lives ( `/a/b/c/d` ). `sed` is used with its search/replace function as a "finder". `,` is the separator, the pattern we search for is `^\(.*/\)\?\([^/]*\)` : `^` is the start of the string. Escaped parentheses surround the first capture group as `\(.*/\)` - a greedy search up to a `/` character, can include other `/`s with the 2nd capture group determining which `/`. Note that the use of `,` as a separator allows us to have the unescaped `/`. `\?` means zero or one of the first capture group. (useful, e.g. if `d/file` were passed in)....

Comment: The second capture group `\([^/]*\)` catches zero or more non-`/` characters. This is useful if no parent were actually passed in, e.g. `file`. I would actually put a `$` for the end of the string after that last parentheses, but what's there works. So, our search pattern was between the first and second `,` characters. In between the second and third (last) `,` characters we have the replacement, `\2` meaning the second capturing group (second part inside escaped parentheses), i.e. everything after the last `/` from the result of `dirname`.

Comment: So, in the example given: result of `dirname` is `/a/b/c/d`. `\(.*/\)\?` gives `/a/b/c/` (as `\1`, incidentally), which isn't included in the `sed` replacement - i.e. it gets cut away. `\([^/]*\)` captures `d` as `\2`. The replacement is `\2`, so the output is `d`.

Answer (score 2):

`dirname` and `basename` should be used for this task.

The short answer is

```
dirname /a/b/c/d/file | xargs basename
=> d
```

The first step, getting the `dirname` of the path, yields the path of the parent folder, as seen below.

```
dirname /a/b/c/d/file
=> /a/b/c/d
```

The path of the parent folder is then piped to another command with `|`. Since `basename` (and `dirname`) don't run on streams and instead just on parametized inputs, you cannot directly pipe the results to `basename` with `| basename`. This however is fixed by `xargs`, which turns the stream from the pipe into an input for `basename`

This allows the final solution to become

```
dirname /a/b/c/d/file | xargs basename
```

Which could also be written as ...

```
echo '/a/b/c/d/file' | xargs dirname | xargs basename
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Julian67's answer above best, but here is a bit an expanded version:

```
file_path = "a/b/c/d/file.txt"
parent=$(echo $file_path | sed -e 's;\/[^/]*$;;') # cut away "/file.txt";'$' is end of string
parent=$(echo $parent | sed -e 's;.*\/;;')  # cut away "/a/b/c/"
echo $parent # --> you get "d"
```

Comment: In case the script becomes a multiline solution, how can it be aliased to a command for cmder (where should one store it? what type of file?)

Comment: @Artur sure, just combine the two `sed` commands into one: `sed -e 's+/*[^/]*$++ ; s+.*/++'` (note that `;` is a confusing choice of regex/replacement delimiter, because it's already the command separator in sed)